# Empty HTML textarea input doesn't show up in PDF generated by mPDF

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I'm generating a PDF from a HTML form using mPDF. The form contains a couple of `textarea` tags (among other things). If the user doesn't enter anything in one `textarea` (they don't have to), that `textarea` doesn't show up in the PDF.

This is what it looks like with text in the `textarea`:
[image]

This is what it looks like without text:
[image]

I would like the empty `textarea` to show up as an empty box in the PDF. It looks fine in the HTML page, but not in the PDF.

I've tried the following:

- Entering a blankspace in the `textarea`.
- Styling the border with CSS: "`border: 1px solid #000`".
- Setting the font colour of the `textarea` to white using CSS ("`color: #fff`") and adding some text to it. The text is white in the HTML, but in the PDF it shows up as black.

Is there a way to make mPDF render a textarea without text as an empty box, just as it looks in the webrowser (I'm using Firefox btw.)?

Comment: you have any exemple code to see?

Comment: Looks like a known [issue](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/838). Have tried using `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @DelenaMalan and I think he has some check in the values ​​before showing the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `&nbsp;` to an empty textarea forces mPDF to render it.

Thanks to Delena Malan for pointing this out!

(I guess that I should've checked the issue tracker for mPDF before asking this)